# Where is standard output for android development on Netbeans?

Tags: android, netbeans, output

I am developing an android app on netbeans.  If, for example, I were to add System.out.println("Hello World") attached to a button click, it does not output anywhere.  Am I missing something basic?

This also means I can never see if exceptions are being thrown or anything.  If my app works it works and if not I am developing 'blind'.  Help?

Answer (score 0):

On Android all of those go to the on device logcat.  Not sure how you'd see that with netbeans, but you'd need to hook it up to adb logcat in some fashion.